# Android Maven project have problems with resources

Tags: android, maven

I have an Android project but in maven. That project was imported from existing gradle sources because of customer. Currently I have found all dependencies that I need (I hope) so I can build APK using maven. APK from maven can be installed and launched with no problems but if I want to run project on emulator and debug It, I can't... There is something strange with the resources, I can't point to existing resource by "@string" or "@mipmap" so IDE is telling me that there is no AndroidManifest (there is but with resource problems).
[those resources exist in res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWnJ9.png)
[those resources exist in res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ZJY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, that was the matter of module settings in Intellij ( Module settings -> select android module -> Structure -> set everything that You need).